# PyTorch DDP TCP-related error when running on DGX Cloud

Tags: sockets, pytorch, nvidia, distributed-computing

I have a training loop set up in PyTorch and have added support for Distributed Data Parallel as per [Fault-Tolerant Distributed Training With `torchrun`](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/ddp_series_fault_tolerance.html). I have also Dockerised my training and the training loop runs without issue both on an Ubuntu server on "bare metal" and when running inside a Docker container, so long as I specify `--ipc=host`.

However, I need to run this training on [DGX Cloud](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/dgx-cloud/) and when I attempt to run the same training using the NGC CLI (with `ngc batch run`) the training fails and I receive a `RuntimeError`:

```
RuntimeError: The client socket has failed to connect to any network address of (5094242, 42185). The client socket has failed to connect to 0.77.187.98:42185 (errno: 110 - Connection timed out).
```

The full traceback is included in the question footer.

What potential differences could be responsible for the different behaviour between a "local" node (whether running inside or outside a Docker container) and the environment on DGX, and which of these should I begin with investigating?

Are there any known issues with DDP or `torchrun` that relate to the error I'm experiencing?

Pointers are welcome as I am not an expert on distributed training or inter-process communication.

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/./sushi/train.py", line 179, in main
    ddp_setup(backend=cfg.dist_backend)
  File "/workspace/./sushi/train.py", line 179, in main
    ddp_setup(backend=cfg.dist_backend)
  File "/workspace/./sushi/train.py", line 172, in ddp_setup
    distributed.init_process_group(backend=backend)
  File "/workspace/./sushi/train.py", line 172, in ddp_setup
    distributed.init_process_group(backend=backend)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 900, in init_process_group
    store, rank, world_size = next(rendezvous_iterator)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 900, in init_process_group
    store, rank, world_size = next(rendezvous_iterator)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/rendezvous.py", line 245, in _env_rendezvous_handler
    store = _create_c10d_store(master_addr, master_port, rank, world_size, timeout)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/rendezvous.py", line 245, in _env_rendezvous_handler
    store = _create_c10d_store(master_addr, master_port, rank, world_size, timeout)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/rendezvous.py", line 176, in _create_c10d_store
    return TCPStore(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/rendezvous.py", line 176, in _create_c10d_store
    return TCPStore(
RuntimeError: The client socket has failed to connect to any network address of (5094242, 42185). The client socket has failed to connect to 0.77.187.98:42185 (errno: 110 - Connection timed out).
RuntimeError: The client socket has failed to connect to any network address of (5094242, 42185). The client socket has failed to connect to 0.77.187.98:42185 (errno: 110 - Connection timed out).
```